Remote Desktop / Windows App now only shows a black screen. How can I get the desktop to be shown?
Environment

Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB running 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS (Debian GNU/Linux
12 bookworm).
MacOS Sequoia 15.1 with Windows App 11.0.6

Situation
With an earlier version (can't remember which) of 32-bit RPiOS and MS Remote Desktop (and its successor Windows App), I could remote into my Pi from my Mac and use the Pi's desktop. I updated the RPiOS (which seemed to include something related to Wayland) after which the Pi only showed a black screen (although a context menu was sometimes available).
I clean installed the latest 64-bit RPiOS (see details above) with no improvement (and, actually, the context menu has gone away). Tried the 32-bit RPiOS with no resolution.
Questions

How can I return to normal remote desktop operation?
What caused this issue?

TiA!

What on earth is "MacOS Sequoia 15.1 with Windows App 11.0.6"? what has it to do with Pi? I have no problems with Raspberry Pi OS from my MacMini.

Have you read https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/a-new-release-of-raspberry-pi-os

Windows App is the new "branding" of MS Remote Desktop. I use that on my MacBook Pro running macOS Sequoia 15.1 to access my RPi. I will read your referenced article. Tx! BTW, what do you use on your MacMini to do this?

I use RealVNC and have used other VNC clients in the past. There are a number of VNC clients which should work but since the change to Wayland those using X didn't work but labwc with wayvnc seems to support X.

Tx! I confirmed labwc & wayvnc are installed & running however there is no change in behaviour attempting to connect via Windows App from my Mac. I've reached my GAFF limit and must have dinner… Thank you for assistance! Maybe I can sell the Pi… (And, yes, the MS marketing gurus that named "Windows App" need their head examined… However, it does follow their trend of maintaining max confusion… Sigh…

DO NOT put detail in Comments; EDIT your Question. You have provided no diagnostics so it is impossible to help without. I can't imagine WHY you would bother with a Windows app on a Mac. My Pi all work perfectly well, it is just a case of knowing how to configure both ends.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/149389/8697 may help.

Sorry if I'm a newbie. I wouldn't know what diagnostics would be required nor how to access them. I'm not using a "Windows" app, I'm using a macOS app created by Microsoft with the odious name "Windows" attached to it; it used to be known as "Windows Remote Desktop". And yes, I am trying to understand how to "…configure both ends…". Thank you for the link. I had thought enabling wayvnc would automagically disable VNC; I'll try that. Thank you for your assistance.

You DON'T need to "disable VNC".
AFAIK "Windows Remote Desktop" REQUIRES VNC (as do practically every remote protocol except nfs or ssh).
